# Regarding a small confusion about DataReader

Tags: ado.net, datareader

I was reading about DataReader and found a statement about DataReader which is not clear. here it is

DataReader fetches the records from database and stores in the network buffer and gives whenever requests. It releases the records as query executes and do not
wait for the entire query to execute. Hence very fast as compare to the DataSet which releases the data after loading all the data in memory.

1) it says that **DataReader** fetches the records from database and stores in the network buffer?
i really do not understand what is network buffer? 
can anyone tell me **what does it mean network buffer**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187602.aspx). The network buffer is in-memory storage on the client that will hold a certain amount of data which is generally smaller that the entire dataset. As data is read from the buffer, it will be re-filled with more data from the database.

Comment: +1, with the clarification that this does not mean that all the results of a query are all pre-loaded to the client. The buffer is often much smaller than the result set, and the buffer is also used to load results into a dataadapter/dataset.

Comment: when network buffer is a area in memory then they could say bufferm why they use the term like  network buffer....any special reason?